# Getting an error code in Python that df is not defined

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to data, so after a few lessons on importing data in python, I tried the following codes in my jupter notebook but keep getting an error saying df not defined. I need help.
The code I wrote is as follows;

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/indicator/SH.TBS.INCD?downloadformat=csv"
df = pd.read_csv(https://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/indicator/SH.TBS.INCD?downloadformat=csv)
```

After running the third code, I got a series of reports on jupter notebook but one that stood out was "df not defined"

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your data is a ZIP file containing multiple CSV files. You need to download the data, unpack the ZIP file, and then read one CSV file at a time.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have unzipped the file yet it can't read it. I have a screenshot of it but don't know how to upload an image on this platform. What do you think I should do?

Comment: If the file is unzipped, then you will need to update what you are asking Pandas to read. The file itself is a folder which contains 3 separate files.

Right now, you are doing: read(FOLDER)
What you need to do is: read(FOLDER/FILE1)

And do this for each file in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

> If you can give more details on the problem(etc: screenshots), debugging will become more easier

One possibility for the error is that the response content accessed by the url(https://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/indicator/SH.TBS.INCD?downloadformat=csv) is a zip file, which may prevent `pandas` from processing it further.

Comment: Thank you for your response.Yes, the url is a zip file. What do I need to do about it?

Comment: I told a screenshot after unzipping the file and importing it to jupyter notebook. I can't upload the screenshot to you on this platform. I don't know why.